# Using conditionals on callbacks rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, conditional-statements

I have a callback on my comment model that creates a notification that gets sent out to the appropriate members but I don't want it to create a notification if the current_member is commenting on his own commentable object. I've tried using the unless conditional like this:

```
after_create :create_notification, on: :create, unless: Proc.new { |commentable| commentable.member == current_member }

def create_notification
    subject = "#{member.user_name}"
    body = "wrote you a <b>Comment</b> <p><i>#{content}</i></p>"
    commentable.member.notify(subject, body, self)
end
```

But I get this error: `undefined local variable or method 'current_member' for #<Comment:0x746e008`

How do I get this to work like I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty atypical to try to use `current_user` or things like that from the model layer. One problem is that you're really coupling your model layer to the current state of the controller layer, which will make unit testing your models much more difficult and error-prone.

What I would recommend is to not use an `after_create` hook to do this, and instead create the notifications at the controller layer.  This will give you access to `current_user` without needing to jump through any hoops.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't need to call current_member anyways I just used `unless: Proc.new { |comment| comment.member.id == comment.commentable.member.id }` instead